# Split a Relative Layout with wrap_content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I got a `RelativeLayout` like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Inside this Layout, there are some `TextView` and other stuff, through which the height of the Layout is defined, because it is set to `wrap_content` like you can see above.

Now I want to have have two Views in the `RelativeLayout` who share the space(in respect to width) but fill the whole Layout. The purpose behind this is, that I want to have two `onClickListener`. In other words: I want to kind of split the layout in two Views next to another (horizontally).

I tried to put a LinearLayout inside the RelativeLayout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/togoTrueTrigger"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/togoFalseTrigger"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

It takes the whole with of the `RelativeLayout` and one `TextView` takes the left 50% and the other one the right 50%. That is exactly what I want. **BUT** I also want them to take the whole Height.

What I can't do: Set the Height of the LinearLayout to `match_parent`. This is not possible, because the whole thing is inside another layout and this would adjust the Height in relation to this layout.

**EDIT: This is my new approach**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="15dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/togoTrue"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Pickup"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/itemConfiguration"
                            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

                        <com.bhargavms.podslider.PodSlider
                            android:id="@+id/togoSwitch"
                            android:layout_width="75dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            app:numberOfPods="2"
                            app:selectedPodColor="@color/colorAccent"
                            app:mainSliderColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                            app:podColor="#ffffff"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/togoFalse"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Vor Ort"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/itemConfiguration"
                            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>


                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/togoTrueTrigger"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
                            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/togoFalseTrigger"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
                            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

                    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Unfortunately this still doesn't work.

**EDIT:**
Here is a sketch of what I want. The first picture is the layout and the second shows the same layout with a blue and a red view. These Views are the ones I try to create.

[image]

Comment: If there are other `Views` in your `RelativeLayout` then you would also have to constrain them when changing to `ConstraintLayout`. One of the aims of the `ConstraintLayout` is to flatten the view hierarchy, so there are fewer nested layout. The constraints in a `ConstraintLayout` only work on its direct children in which case you wouldn't wrap your `TextViews` inside a `LinearLayout` but just constrain the `TextViews` themselves to other `Views` and parent. If you want more help with converting to `ConstraintLayout` it would be helpful if you updated your question with the whole layout.

Comment: @plaskoff please see my edit

Comment: @progNewbie could You draw sample pic what You want? A picture says a thousand words.

Comment: @deadfish: please see my edit

Comment: @progNewbie ok, could You paste Your actual layout?

Comment: @deadfish I pasted it in the previous edit

Comment: @progNewbie so You want layout with three views in horizontal view? I am trying to figure out what You want. However Your pasted previously layout which is containing more than three view. Please clarify this or paste Your latest "almost working" layout.

Comment: @deadfish I have a Layout and inside this layout there is some stuff (atm a textview a slider and again a textview) But it does not really matter what is inside. Now I just want to VIEWS one taking 50% of the Layout from the left and one doing the same from the right (like I was drawing in my sketch). The Height of these Views should match the Layout height.

Comment: @deadfish BUT I can't just use normal `match_parent`, because the Layout is inside another layout and than the `match_parent` would align on that parent one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174804/discussion-between-deadfish-and-prognewbie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are three views inside of the main layout and two views with 50% width obove of them. I believe this is Your answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/togoTrue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pickup"
        android:textAppearance="@style/itemConfiguration"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    <com.bhargavms.podslider.PodSlider
        android:id="@+id/togoSwitch"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:mainSliderColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:numberOfPods="2"
        app:podColor="#ffffff"
        app:selectedPodColor="@color/colorAccent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/togoFalse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Vor Ort"
        android:textAppearance="@style/itemConfiguration"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/togoTrueTrigger"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#44ffff00"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".5" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/togoFalseTrigger"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#4400ff00"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".5" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/).

Though initially a bit intimidating it does everything all the other layouts can do and much more (including what you just asked by using "match_constraint").

It's part of the Support Library as well, so it's usable in older projects.

Comment: Somehow even this did not work out. Maybe I am doing something wrong. I changed the RelativeLayout to the ConstraintLayout and set `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` in my LinearLayout.

Comment: I assumed you couldn't use match_parent because you wanted to occupy all space between the parent top and another view vertically. If you use the visual editor for ConstraintLayout anchor the bottom of your LinearLayout to the other view and then set height as "match_constraint". That should make it expand correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want these two `Views` for the purpose of setting an `OnClickListener` on them. This is how I would go about it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/togoTrue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pickup"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/togoSwitch"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.bhargavms.podslider.PodSlider
        android:id="@+id/togoSwitch"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        app:numberOfPods="2"
        app:selectedPodColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:mainSliderColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:podColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/togoTrue"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/togoFalse"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/togoFalse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Vor Ort"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/togoSwitch"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/togoTrueTrigger"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/togoFalseTrigger"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/togoFalseTrigger"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/togoTrueTrigger"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```